# When I submit an abstract for a conference through email, should I include my name and contact info in the same PDF file?

Tags: paper-submission, conference, abstract

I have to submit an abstract for a conference in MLA 8th format. The deadline is on the 20th of this month (August 2023). The conference committee has not specified anything regarding this, so I am confused about where to include my name and contact information. Should I include it in the PDF that contains the abstract or separately as a body in the mail?

Comment: We can't know, you've got to ask them.